# Object object instead of string when pushing into array mongoose

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

i have following function to inserting ingredients:

```
router.post('/api/recipes/ingredient/post', function (req, res) {
    console.log('before for');
    var names = req.body.ing_name;
    var amounts = req.body.ing_amount;
    for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        var ingredientItem = {ingredient_name: names[i].toString(), amount: amounts[i].toString()};
        Recipe.update({name: req.body.name},
            {$push: {"ingredients": ingredientItem}},
            function (err, res) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                    console.log("ERROR OCCURRED, COULD NOT SAVE USER IN DATABASE");
                }
                else {
                    console.log("USER SUCCESSFULLY MODIFIED IN DATABASE");
                }
            });
    }
});
```

but in collection it ends up being:

```
"ingredients" : [ 
        [ 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("59b8726b4de01a2958511871"),
                "amount" : "[object Object]",
                "ingredient_name" : "[object Object]"
            }
        ], 
        [ 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("59b8726b4de01a2958511872"),
                "amount" : "[object Object]",
                "ingredient_name" : "[object Object]"
            }
        ]
    ]
```

i run out of ideas how to fix it, maybe anyone would have an idea?
When i do typeof on names[i].toString for example before pushing it has type of String

Comment: What do you get when you console log `names[i].toString()`

Comment: that object Object thingy which makes even less sense for me now actually

Comment: well then it's not an insertion problem the problem is somewhere else.

Now please console log `name[i]` and paste it's result so that I can see what is being converted into string

Comment: {ingr_name: 'bleble'} but why?

Comment: You are converting a object into string due to which this is shown `"[object Object]"`

Comment: How can i extract only value of ingr_name from there?

Comment: do something like this `names[i].ingr_name` or `names[i]->ingr_name`. Please update me if it solves your problem

Comment: sorry you have to do something like this `names.ingr_name` or `names->ingr_name`

Comment: You, Sir are a genius, it works properly :)

Comment: let me post the answer and can you please accept so that it can help other people too. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are facing this problem because you are trying to convert a object into string due to which a string like this is show `"[object Object]"`.

You need to get the `ingr_name` from the object as you told in the comments above. So rather than converting the whole object into string extract the `ingr_name` from the object like this

`names->ingr_name`